# Column sums of a pandas DataFrame (but keep the structure of pandas DataFrame)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a small sample of my dataframe here:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0]], columns = ["CHAP1SEC1", "CHAP1SEC2", "CHAP1SEC3", "CHAP1SEC4", "CHAP1SEC5"], index = [0, 1, 2, 3])
```

Note: the variables are binary.

[image: sample dataframe printed]

I'm trying to essentially merge these 4 rows into one row, keeping any non-zero entries in the columns. Since the variables are binary, my go-to was just to take column sums.

`df.sum(axis = 1)`

[image: attempted output printed]

However, while this gives me the values I want, it is not returned in the same original dataframe structure.

Essentially, I would like to take the column sums of a dataframe, while keeping the structure of that dataframe. Ideally, my output would be as follows:

[image: ideal output printed]

I feel there must be a super simple solution that I am just not seeing and I couldn't find a similar question already posted on SO.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: That did the job, thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one way to do it

```
df.sum(axis=0).to_frame().T
```

or

```
df.sum().to_frame().T
```

```
    CHAP1SEC1   CHAP1SEC2   CHAP1SEC3   CHAP1SEC4   CHAP1SEC5
0           1           0           1           1           1
```